# How to move several folders using double wildcard?

Tags: mv, wildcards

I am trying to move all the folders that have the digit 1 in between `(glove.6B.60d.txt)` and `(model)`

```
mv "./*.txt)(1)(m*" "/home/e1"
```

but I get the error message

```
mv: cannot stat './*.txt)(1)(m*': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I am in the same folder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globs are not expanded inside quotes - you'd need something like

```
./*".txt)(1)(m"*
```

or

```
./*.txt")(1)("m*
```

or

```
./*.txt\)\(1\)\(m*
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a most unfortunate choice of directory names since you need some level of quotes in those shell commands; yet the quotes also prevent wildcard expansion.

But you can piece the name together from multiple partially-quoted strings; like

```
mv  *".txt)("1")(model"*    /home/e1
```

Or simplify to

```
mv *.txt??1??model*    /home/e1
```

This assumes that you always have *.txt, then any two characters, then a digit 1, then again any two characters, then model* which should work quite well.

And even refine this to accept *all* digits at once:

```
mv *.txt??[0-9]??model*    /home/e1
```

Notice that the quotes are used to *protect* special characters from the shell, but here you *want* wildcard expansion.